# `gcloud app browse` opens wrong URL

Tags: google-app-engine

In my environment `gcloud app browse` opens wrong directory.

Most probably my old config remain somewhere. How can I change it? Where the URI info is saved?

Comment: try "gcloud init"

Comment: Thanks! I could change the project name.